# Ploblema a usar una funcion del encabezado <curses.h>

Tags: c, windows

Tengo este código C:

```C
#include <curses.h>
int main(){
    initscr();
    move(10,30);
    printf("Hola");
    return 0;
}
```

Me sale esté error:

```
main.C:(.text+0xf): undefined refernce to 'initfscr'
main.C:(.text+0x23): undefined refernce to 'move'
```

El comando de `gcc` es:

```
gcc main.c -o main.exe
```

Lo hé intalado usando el intalador de MinGW. ¿Como puedo solucionar este problema?.
He intentado desintalarlo y volverlo a instalar pero no funciona.

#### Actualización:

Tambien he linkeado mi proyecto con el frag de `-lncurses` y me sale los mismos problemas:

```bat
gcc -lncurses main.c -o main.exe
```

Comment: Tienes que añadir la libreria. Creo que es con el flag `-lcurses` pero no estoy seguro. Nota que si usas curses los printf lo mas probable es que no salgan en la pantalla, creo que tienes que usar `wprintf` (No recuerdo el nombre exacto, pero tienes que usar la funcion que te da curses)

Comment: Ya lo hise. Instalé todo lo que lleva en el nombre curses.h para evitarme esté ploblema. @Pablochaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando importas ciertas bibliotecas en C se le tiene que especificar un flag específico para indicarle al compilador que estás haciendo uso de otras bibliotecas ([linker](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)), en el caso de [curses.h](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses) se le tiene que especificar que está usando esa librería con el flag `-lncurses` a veces aparece como `-lcurses` de tal manera que tu comando de compilación debe ser

```
gcc main.c -o main.exe -lncurses
gcc main.c -o main.exe -lcurses
```

Y para una biblioteca con debugging se usa `-lncurses_g` o `-lcurses_g` sea el caso

Comment: -lcurses no se puede encontrar -lcurses. -lncurses me sale los mismos errores y lpdcurses tambien. Actualizaré mi pregunta. Gracias antes no tenia conocimiento sobre los frag de mingw.

Comment: Otro ejemplo es cuando haces uso de `<Math.h>` donde se le tiene que especificar que estás usando esa biblioteca con el linker `-lm` y quedaría como `gcc -lm main.c -o main.exe`

Comment: Hmm, ¿Cuál distribución estás usando? (Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, etc)

De igual manera te dejo esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277192/how-to-install-curses-h-header-fileor-the-package-including-itin-linux) que te puede llegar a servir

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo. Es mi primera vez usando GCC y casí no conosco sus opciones. Aprovechando ¿Sabes cual flag especifica el idioma que estoy usando?. Por ejemplo: C. Me parece fastidioso que al hacer esto: `char* name="Daniel";` . Me salga esta abvertencia: `Error ISO C++ convent string to char*`

Comment: Estoy usando Windows.

Comment: Viendo un poco creo que ese error ISO te sale con C++, realmente yo no sé de C++ pero lo que puedo inferir con una [pregunta que leí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944784/why-is-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-valid-in-c-but-invalid-in-c) es porque C++11 necesita que hagas el casteo indicándole de qué tipo es la variable que vas a almacenar puesto que no se hace automáticamente. Necesitarías poner `char* name = (char*) "Daniel";`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123097/discussion-between-daniel-briceno-and-eduardo).